# callFunctionInBackground Parse swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using the following code :

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getFollowers", withParameters: ["userId":id!,"offset":0 ]) { (result , error) -> Void in

        if let result = result as? [Follower]  {
            print(result)
            for fl in result {

                print(fl)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `print(result)` shows the following:

```
[<Follower: 0x7f8f7253c2f0, objectId: 5h3pcK0GTK, localId: (null)> {
Likes = 2;
description = cggggg;
image = "<PFFile: 0x7f8f7253b220>";
isFollowing = 0;
pushed = 1;
user = "<Spoke.SPKUser: 0x7f8f72564690, objectId: ESczJnhc7c, localId: (null)>";
voice = "<PFFile: 0x7f8f7253e8e0>";}]
```

the weird thing is `print(fl)` shows :

```
fl  myapp.Follower  0x00007fe0c1e6aa90  0x00007fe0c1e6aa90
Parse.PFObject  PFObject        
Likes   Int!    nil
image   PFFile! nil 
isFollowing Bool!   nil 
pushed  Bool!   nil 
user    Spoke.SPKUser!  nil 
voice   PFFile! nil
```

My question is why I cannot get an array of mapped follower objects ?

Comment: You might need to edit your cloud code to make sure it returns the associated data similar to `query.includeKey()`. Or, since I'm not entirely sure if you can do that in cloud code, you could call `f1.fetchIfNeeded()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `@NSManaged` in front of every property of my `PFObject` subclass and it worked